# Docker - How to disable PHP ext / modules

Tags: php, docker, php-extension

I am working on a PHP API and I would like to **disable unused php Modules** inside my **PHP-FPM** image, such as "sqlite3, pdo ..".

I am a docker beginner and I would like to know if is there anything similar to `docker-php-ext-enable` if not what is the best practice for disabling unused php modules.

Comment: How about the `php.ini` file?

Comment: https://hub.docker.com/_/php/

Comment: I have a custom php.ini file under /usr/local/etc/php .. what do you suggest ? I can't find anything helpful on the above link .. php comes with some default modules and I would like to disable some of them.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Finally I found the key point.

Inside docker php container, all the registered modules holds by a configuration file under the below path.

```
/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/*.ini
```

`bash` into the container:

```
docker exec -it php_container_name bash
```

You can list all the enabled modules by `php -m`:

And `cd` into that folder, you can see the relating config files:

```
cd /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/
ls

# output
docker-php-ext-mcrypt.ini  docker-php-ext-mysqli.ini    
docker-php-ext-opcache.ini  opcache-recommended.ini  
docker-php-ext-zip.ini
```

To disable some extension module, make a dir `disabled`, and move that `.ini` file inside it, for example:

```
mkdir disabled
mv docker-php-ext-opcache.ini disabled
mv opcache-recommended.ini
```

Finally, press `Ctrl+D` to exit the container, and then restart the container to make changes work.

```
docker restart php_container_name
```

You can get into the container and run `php -m` to see, the relating extension is gone.

Comment: There's a typo `mkdir disalbled`, can't change it because edits need to be at least 10 edited characters.

Comment: i am using php:7.2.5-fpm and wanna disable pdo_sqlite that shipped with image by default. How to do that?

Comment: @crz in that case (if it was compiled with sqlite), I don't think you can remove it. You should compile php without it

Answer (score 1):

In my case i had to enable/disable `xdebug` extension. I appears that there's some 'magic' that works by (de-)suffixing extensions ini file with `-disabled`.

Once the suffix changes, php somehow magically loads/unloads module. You can check that by running `php -m` command. (maybe this behaviour is only alpine-linux related??)

I wrote additional `docker-php-ext-disable-xdebug` script by taking example from `/usr/local/bin/docker-php-ext-enable-xdebug`:

```
#!/bin/sh

if test -f '/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini'; then
        echo 'Disabling extension xdebug'
        mv '/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini' '/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini-disabled'
else
        echo 'The extension xdebug is not enabled'
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Piggybacking off Alfred's answer but I made these today.

```
alias disDebugCust="docker exec -it xdebugContainer bash -c 'cd /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/ && mkdir -p disabled && mv xdebug.ini disabled && /etc/init.d/apache2 reload'"
alias enDebugCust="docker exec -it xdebugContainer bash -c 'cd /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/disabled && mv xdebug.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/ && /etc/init.d/apache2 reload'"
```

First we exec into the container. 
Then we go to the config folder.
Then we make a new directory called disabled if one doesn't exist. 
Then we move the ini file.
Finally we restart apache.

The second command just moves it back and restarts apache.

Answer (score -5):

Yes that's possible.

Taken from https://hub.docker.com/_/php/

> For example, if you want to have a PHP-FPM image with `iconv`, `mcrypt` and `gd` extensions, you can inherit the base image that you like, and write your own Dockerfile like this:

```
FROM php:7.0-fpm
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
        libfreetype6-dev \
        libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
        libmcrypt-dev \
       libpng12-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) iconv mcrypt \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/ \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd
```

> Remember, you must install dependencies for your extensions manually. If an extension needs custom `configure` arguments, you can use the `docker-php-ext-configure` script like this example.

Comment: So hows the way to disable or uninstall after we have already install that?